# Looping through netcdf files and cbinding each iteration to an object

Tags: r

So I am trying to loop through a folder that contains 30 netcdf files, pull a variable from several layers, process it, and cbind each iteration of this loop to an object. I am working with daily data and I would like each column to represent 1 day of said variable. I seem to be pretty close but cant quite get it to finish. 
Here is my loop:

```
 files <- list.files(path="../07 epic month 1", pattern="*.nc",  full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
mydata <- data.frame()
# Loop over files
for(i in seq_along(files)) {
nc = open.ncdf(files[i])

i = get.var.ncdf(nc,'NO3')
i <- i[ , ,c(9:16, 31:36) ]
  i <- as.vector(i)
    i = data.frame(i)
      i[is.na(i)] <- "0"
        i[ , ] <- sapply(i[ , ], as.numeric)
          i <- as.matrix(i)
            i <- split(i ,1:137241 )
              i <- data.frame(i)
                i <- as.matrix(i)
                  i <- t(i)
                    i <- rowSums(i)
                      i <- data.frame(i)
                        mydata[[i]] 
 }
```

but when I run the loop I get this error:

```
  Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Comment: put `browser()` somewhere in your code and inspect the state of variables during the code execution

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear on what you are extracting from each file, but you can use `lapply` to read file in a loop. I could not test this solution as there is not sample data provided by you and expected output. But, I am sure this will be start for you to work further.

```
mydata_files <- lapply(list.files(), FUN = function(x) {
      nc <- open.ncdf(files(x))
      i  <- get.var.ncdf(nc,'NO3')
      data <- i[ , ,c(9:16, 31:36) ]
      result <- rowSums(data)
      return(result)
})
result <- do.call("cbind", mydata_files )
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys I got it figured out. Just needed a little tweek to run.

```
 files <- list.files(path="../07 epic month 1", pattern="*.nc",  full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
 mydata <- 1:137241
 mydata = data.frame(mydata)
# Loop over files
for(i in seq_along(files)) {
 nc = open.ncdf(files[i])

 # Read the whole nc file and read the length of the varying dimension (here, the 3rd dimension, specifically time)
 out = get.var.ncdf(nc,'NO3')
  out <- out[ , ,c(9:16, 31:36) ]
   out <- as.vector(out)
    out = data.frame(out)
      out[is.na(out)] <- "0"
        out[ , ] <- sapply(out[ , ], as.numeric)
          out <- as.matrix(out)
            out <- split(out ,1:137241 )
              out <- data.frame(out)
                out <- as.matrix(out)
                  out <- t(out)
                    out <- rowSums(out)
                      mydata <- cbind(mydata, out)

}
```